# Prolog: Head of a variable list is not instantated

Tags: list, prolog, instantiation-error

I'm writing a simple code generating a simple list with 5 numbers whose first variable should be positive and I'm trying to understand why this code fails

```
test([H|T]) :- H > 0, length(T,4).
```

when I call with

```
 length(X,5), test(X).
```

it shows me the following error:

> *ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated*

When I debug the code, the `H` variable in `test` isn't instantiated.

Anyone know why?

Comment: How can it even know it should be a number?

Comment: try the query `length(X, 5).`.

Comment: `length(X, 5)` gives you a list of... well....  length 5, but whose elements aren't known yet. So they're variable. `length/2` doesn't generate the actual elements.

Comment: You get an instantiation error for the same reason that, simply, `H > 0` gives you one.

Comment: in other words, try the query `H > 0.` at your Prolog prompt.  `H` is not instantiated because *you* have not instantiated it to anything yet. But if you do e.g. `H = 3, H > 0.`, or `H is 1 + 2, H > 0.`, *then* it works. see also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/instantiation-error/info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that your rule for `test([H|T])` doesn't describe in Prolog that `H` is a positive integer. It only tests if `H > 0`, which fails since `H` has not instantiation. Just attempting to compare an uninstantiated variable with a number (`H > 0` in this case) doesn't cause Prolog to assume you intended `H` to be a number, and further, doesn't instantiate `H`.

Further, your rule for `test/1` doesn't describe the rest of the list (`T`) other than to force that it be length 4. Since you're query establishes the rule that the length of the original list be 5, this stipulation is redundant.

You appear to be wanting to define `test(L)` such that it means `L` is an arbitrary list of positive integers. This is generally done using CLP(FD):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

test(X) :- X ins 1..10000.
```

This rule says that `X` is a list whose values are in the range 1 to 10000. The appropriate query to generate the lists of length 5 would then be:

```
?- length(X, 5), test(X), label(X).
X = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
X = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2] ;
X = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3] ;
X = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4] ;
X = [1, 1, 1, 1, 5] ;
...
```

If you want to restrict it further and say that elements need to be unique, you can use `all_different/1`:

```
test(X) :- X ins 1..10000, all_different(X).

?- length(X, 5), test(X), label(X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10] ;
...
```

Comment: `all_distinct/1` has stronger propagation and should typically be used instead of `all_different/1`, though I doubt this makes any difference in this particular case.

Comment: @Fatalize thank you, good suggestion. And I agree, it's probably splitting hairs in this question/answer scenario.